# Build error after installing TXTextControl

Tags: c#, .net, gac, txtextcontrol

I have installed TXTextControl .NET 15.1 with a valid license key on a brand-new Windows Server 2016, and I have installed Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 including .NET 4.6.2 and .NET 4.7.2.

When I build my C# project (targeting .NET 4.6.2), I get the following error:

```
(CompileLicxFiles target) -> 
licenses.licx(1): error LC0004: Exception occurred creating type 'TXTextControl.ServerTextControl, TXTextControl, Version=15.1.800.500, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6b83fe9a75cfb638' System.DllNotFoundException: The TX Text Control kernel DLL file could not be found.
```

The error `The TX Text Control kernel DLL file could not be found` hinted at something missing in the GAC, which I then proceeded to check out.

Running the `gacutil.exe` that came with .NET 4.7.2 indicated that the necessary registrations for

- `txkernel.dll`
- `txic.dll`
- `txtools.dll`

were not there.

I then went on and installed them manually, both the x86 and AMD64 versions, from their respective locations:

- `C:\Program Files\The Imaging Source Europe GmbH\TX Text Control 15.1.NET\BrowserBin\txkernel.dll`
- `C:\Program Files\The Imaging Source Europe GmbH\TX Text Control 15.1.NET\BrowserBin64\txkernel.dll`
- etc.

But it still didn't work!

I then contacted support, but their reply was that my license was no longer valid for support, so they basically refused to answer any questions about the product.

After a while I then got the supporter to say that the company never test OLD versions of TXTextControl on NEW versions of Windows, so my best bet would be to purchase a new license.

Since the license is pretty expensive, and our (PERPETUAL!) license is perfectly valid for running the product, I am determined to find a solution to this issue.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some struggling, I found the solution: Install .NET 3.5 BEFORE installing TXTextControl .NET.

My hypothesis is that the TXTextControl installer fails to check the exit codes, when running `gacutil.exe`, so it doesn't detect that the registrations have failed.

This means that the recipe for solving this problem (which I post here for Bingle to pick up), is to:

- wipe any GAC registrations you may have made in an attempt to manually install the TXTextControl DLLs
- uninstall TXTextControl .NET
- go to Server Manager and "Add Roles and Features", and then on the "Features" pane, you put a checkmark next to ".NET Framework 3.5 Features" (which causes a single checkmark to be in ".NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)")
- reinstall TXTextControl .NET

After this was done, I could build my code!

Answer (score 0):

From having similar sounding issues with the ASP.Net version, make sure that you also have [Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=40784) installed as since v25 this has been required and for any machines that don't already have that installed then the ASP.Net version throws similar errors about txic.dll.